# What is keystore, private key, upload key, signing key, app signing key, upload certificate, and app signing certificate in android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-play, keystore

In Android app development, there are several terms and concepts that are related to managing the security and integrity of the apps, but they are very confusing to me.

```
key store

public key

private key

upload key

signing key 

app signing key 

upload certificate

app signing certificate
```

What are they and how they are related to each other?

Comment: A good place to start is the docs: https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing